# Wait for RabbitMQ Threads to finish in Windows Service OnStop()

Tags: c#, multithreading, windows-services, rabbitmq

I am working on a windows service written in C# (.NET 4.5, VS2012), which uses RabbitMQ (receiving messages by subscription). There is a class which derives from `DefaultBasicConsumer`, and in this class are two actual consumers (so two channels). Because there are two channels, two threads handle incoming messages (from two different queues/routing keys) and both call the same `HandleBasicDeliver(...)` function.

Now, when the windows service `OnStop()` is called (when someone is stopping the service), I want to let both those threads finish handling their messages (if they are currently processing a message), sending the ack to the server, and then stop the service (abort the threads and so on).

I have thought of multiple solutions, but none of them seem to be really good. Here's what I tried:

- using one mutex; each thread tries to take it when entering HandleBasicDeliver, then releases it afterwards. When `OnStop()` is called, the main thread tries to grab the same mutex, effectively preventing the RabbitMQ threads to actually process any more messages. The disadvantage is, only one consumer thread can process a message at a time.
- using two mutexes: each RabbitMQ thread has uses a different mutex, so they won't block each other in the HandleBasicDeliver() - I can differentiate which
  thread is actually handling the current message based on the routing key. Something like:

  ```
  HandleBasicDeliver(...)
  {
      if(routingKey == firstConsumerRoutingKey)
      {
          // Try to grab the mutex of the first consumer
      }
      else
      {
          // Try to grab the mutex of the second consumer
      }
  }
  ```

  When `OnStop()` is called, the main thread will try to grab both mutexes; once both mutexes are "in the hands" of the main thread, it can proceed with stopping the service. The problem: if another consumer would be added to this class, I'd need to change a lot of code.
- using a counter, or `CountdownEvent`. Counter starts off at 0, and each time `HandleBasicDeliver()` is entered, counter is safely incremented using the Interlocked class. After the message is processed, counter is decremented. When `OnStop()` is called, the main thread checks if the counter is 0. Should this condition be fulfilled, it will continue. However, after it checks if counter is 0, some RabbitMQ thread might begin to process a message.
- When `OnStop()` is called, closing the connection to the RabbitMQ (to make sure no new messages will arrive), and then waiting a few seconds ( in case there are any messages being processed, to finish processing) before closing the application. The problem is, the exact number of seconds I should wait before shutting down the apllication is unknown, so this isn't an elegant or exact solution.

I realize the design does not conform to the Single Responsibility Principle, and that may contribute to the lack of solutions. However, could there be a good solution to this problem without having to redesign the project?

Answer (score 1):

We do this in our application, The main idea is to use a **CancellationTokenSource**

On your windows service add this:

```
private static readonly CancellationTokenSource CancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
```

Then in your rabbit consumers do this:
1. change from using `Dequeue` to `DequeueNoWait`
2. have your rabbit consumer check the cancellation token

Here is our code:

```
        public async Task StartConsuming(IMessageBusConsumer consumer, MessageBusConsumerName fullConsumerName, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var queueName = GetQueueName(consumer.MessageBusConsumerEnum);

            using (var model = _rabbitConnection.CreateModel())
            {
                // Configure the Quality of service for the model. Below is how what each setting means.
                // BasicQos(0="Don't send me a new message until I’ve finished",  _fetchSize = "Send me N messages at a time", false ="Apply to this Model only")
                model.BasicQos(0, consumer.FetchCount.Value, false);
                var queueingConsumer = new QueueingBasicConsumer(model);

                model.BasicConsume(queueName, false, fullConsumerName, queueingConsumer);


                var queueEmpty = new BasicDeliverEventArgs(); //This is what gets returned if nothing in the queue is found.

                while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    var deliverEventArgs = queueingConsumer.Queue.DequeueNoWait(queueEmpty);
                    if (deliverEventArgs == queueEmpty)
                    {
                        // This 100ms wait allows the processor to go do other work.
                        // No sense in going back to an empty queue immediately. 
                        // CancellationToken intentionally not used!
                        // ReSharper disable once MethodSupportsCancellation
                        await Task.Delay(100);  
                        continue;
                    }
                    //DO YOUR WORK HERE!
                  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I have some follow-up questions. Since I am using a DefaultBasicConsumer, there is a callback function (`HandleBasicDeliver`) being called whenever a message arrives. I could check the CancellationToken right after it enters that function (and before it starts processing the message). But what happends if `Service.OnStop()` is called (and `CancellationTokenSource.Cancel` is set) right after the RabbitMQ Thread has started processing the message, and has passed the `if(IsCancellationRequested)`? The service will shutdown while the message is being processed.

Comment: In your OnStop method you need to wait for the processing of the current message.  So you'd have something like this: `Task.WaitAll(tasks, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15));`

Answer (score 1):

Usually, how we ensure a windows service not stop before processing completes is to use some code like below. Hope that help.

```
    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        // start the worker thread
        _workerThread = new Thread(WorkMethod)
        {
            // !!!set to foreground to block windows service be stopped
            // until thread is exited when all pending tasks complete
            IsBackground = false
        };
        _workerThread.Start();
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        // notify the worker thread to stop accepting new migration requests
        // and exit when all tasks are completed
        // some code to notify worker thread to stop accepting new tasks internally

        // wait for worker thread to stop
        _workerThread.Join();
    }
```